# object copy visual studio error pop up: std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, memory, std, bad-alloc

I want to copy page contents to another Page object. 
However it has the error, I think it is related to memory allocation. 
I haven't found specific reason. Anyone explain about reason? 
I attached my source code part of coping object. Thank

```
DB.Pages = new Page[numPages];
Page* tmp_Pages = new Page[numPages];

uint count = 0;
for(uint p = 0;p < numPages; p++){
    uint *data = new uint[MAX_NUM_NODES_PER_DATA];
    uint *tmp_data = DB.getPageByID(p)->data;
    memcpy(data, tmp_data, sizeof(uint) * MAX_NUM_DATAS_PER_PAGE);
    tmp_Pages[count].data = data;
    count++;
}
memcpy(DB.Pages, tmp_Pages, sizeof(Page) * numPages);
```

mlock.c file error point
void __cdecl _unlock (int locknum)
{
        /*
         * leave the critical section.
         */
        LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc(memory location 0x002afa90)

Comment: You may want to include the error too

Comment: It is collect to copy from original objection to new object? By deep copy technique?

Comment: Suspicious that you use different size constants to allocate and to copy an array:
uint *data = new uint[MAX_NUM_NODES_PER_DATA];
memcpy(data, tmp_data, sizeof(uint) * MAX_NUM_DATAS_PER_PAGE);
I guess it might need to be MAX_NUM_DATAS_PER_PAGE in both cases.